# How to force Backbone.js not to delete siblings of 'default' values?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This question is quite difficult to describe in words, so let me know if it needs clarifying.
I'm very new to backbone.js, so it might be a silly question.

I want to use backbone to easily create graphs (highcharts library). I want to keep a massive json object with all common highcharts settings in my 'defaults' object in model. Then, I want to override some of the variables, for instance the one containing name of dom element the chart needs to be rendered in.

Here's my code:

```
var app = {
    Views:{},
    Models:{},
    Collections:{},
    init:function(){
        new app.Views.PageView();
    }
};

$().ready(_.bind(app.init,app));

 app.Models.chart = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        chart:{
           renderTo:'charts',
           backgroundColor:'#e1e1e1',
           height:200,
           width:200,
           defaultSeriesType:'spline',
           spacingRight:40,
           animation:false
        },
        colors:['#000', '#AA4643'],
        title:{
           text:''
        },
//lots lots lots of other attributes defined here.

app.Views.ChartView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render : function() {
        var chartContainer = this.model.attributes.chart.renderTo;
        $('#charts').append("<div id="+chartContainer+"></div>");

        new Highcharts.Chart(this.model.toJSON());
        return this;
    }
});

var chartDetails = [{chart:{renderTo:'div1'}},{chart:{renderTo:'div2'}}];

app.Views.PageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#charts"),

    initialize : function(){
        this.chartCollection = new app.Collections.Charts(chartDetails);
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        var that = this;
        _.each(this.chartCollection.models, function(item){
            that.renderChart(item);
        })
    },

    renderChart : function (item) {
        var chartView = new app.Views.ChartView({
            model: item
        });
        chartView.render();
    }
});
```

So, the real question here is: when I define a new collection, I provide 'chartDetails' object, which overrides my 'default' specified in model. So, rather than update the defaults.charts.renderTo property, it replaces the full defaults.charts object. How do I make it keep everything what's stored there (backgroundColor, etc), apart from the value I want to replace?

Thanks in advance
k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple approach, if you had a flat representation of your model, would be something along these lines as you can define `defaults` as a function

```
app.Models.Chart = Backbone.Model.extend(
{
    // we're using constructor to set this.options 
    //  as defaults gets called before initialize
    constructor: function (attrs, options)
    {
        this.attrs = attrs;
        Backbone.Model.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments)
    },
    // defaults can be defined as a function, yeah!
    defaults: function ()
    {
        var defaults = {
            renderTo: 'charts',
            backgroundColor: '#e1e1e1',
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
            spacingRight: 40,
            animation: false
        };
        return _.extend({}, defaults, this.attrs);
    }
});
```

I prefer this implementation above an implementation like this because you're not tying your bootstrap together in one go, this might actually trigger unwanted events:

```
app.Models.Chart = Backbone.Model.extend(
{
    initialize: function (attrs, options)
    {
        // this might trigger events, even if you make it {silent: true}
        // and is why I prefer the above implementation instead
        this.set(attrs); 
    },
    defaults: {
        renderTo: 'charts',
        backgroundColor: '#e1e1e1',
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
        spacingRight: 40,
        animation: false
    };
});
```

but since you have a deeply nested instead of a flat representation of your model, you will have to do some additional magic to only replace individual key/value pairs inside the nested object, as you would overwrite the whole object if you decide to extend it as in above example.

Thankfully jQuery's `extend` method, as opposed to underscore.js's `extend` method provides us with a `deep` parameter so that you can do this:

```
app.Models.Chart = Backbone.Model.extend(
{
    // we're using constructor to set this.options 
    //  as defaults gets called before initialize
    constructor: function (attrs, options)
    {
        this.attrs = attrs;
        Backbone.Model.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments)
    },
    // defaults can be defined as a function, yeah!
    defaults: function ()
    {
        var defaults = {
            renderTo: 'charts',
            backgroundColor: '#e1e1e1',
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
            spacingRight: 40,
            animation: false
        };
        return $.extend(true, {}, defaults, this.attrs); // thank you jQuery!
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi. It all seems sensible, but the 'defaults' object is nested, unfortunately. It all comes down to merging this:
`example1 = {
  p1:'a',
  p2:{
      a="one",
      b="two"
  }
}

with this: 

example2 = {
  p2:{
     a="something else"
  }
}


into this:

result = {
  p1:'a',
  p2:{
      a="something else",
      b="two"
  }
}`

Comment: Updated my answer with how do deepmerge

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot! 
Unfortunately it didn't work straight away - you're meant to send over attributes, rather than options - that is, set this.attrs = attr rather than this.options 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the initialize function to  do some custom data processing.

```
myModel = Backbone.Model.extends({
initialize: function(myObject){
// do some stuff with myObject
}
});
```